# Iterate through array backwards error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing some fundamentals with Javascript. Im adding the values of the sub arrays from left to right (These values would be 17,5,1,9,24) and right to left(These values would be 13,3,1,7,21). My left to right function works great!, but my right to left function is throwing an error when it reaches:

```
for(var i = matrixArray.length; i > 0 ; i--){
    rightToLeftHorizontalValues.push(matrixArray[i][i]);
}
```

The error says : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined**

```
var matrixArray = [
    [17, 16, 15, 14, 13],
    [18, 5, 4, 3, 12],
    [19, 6, 1, 2, 11],
    [20, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
];

function matrixFundemental(){

    function leftToRightValues() {
        horizontalTotalLeftToRight = 0;
        leftToRightHorizontalValues = [];    
        for(var i = 0; i < matrixArray.length; i++){
            leftToRightHorizontalValues.push(matrixArray[i][i]);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < leftToRightHorizontalValues.length; i++){
            horizontalTotalLeftToRight += leftToRightHorizontalValues[i];
        }
        console.log(horizontalTotalLeftToRight)
    }

    function rightToLeftValues() {
        horizontalTotalRightToLeft = 0;
        rightToLeftHorizontalValues = [];
        for(var i = matrixArray.length; i > 0 ; i--){
            rightToLeftHorizontalValues.push(matrixArray[i][i]);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < rightToLeftHorizontalValues.length; i++){
            horizontalTotalLeftToRight += rightToLeftHorizontalValues[i];
        }
        console.log(horizontalTotalRightToLeft)
    }

    leftToRightValues();
    rightToLeftValues();
};

matrixFundemental();
```

At this point I cant seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `array.length` will return 5, however, `array[5]` does not exist. There ARE 5 entries, however, the first index starts at zero.

You'll want to iterate from `array.length - 1` (which is 4)

```
for(var i = matrixArray.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--){
    rightToLeftHorizontalValues.push(matrixArray[i][i]);
}
```

Comment: @Jeff Noel That did the trick! I guess i got zoned out for a little bit. Thanks. Ill accept your answer here in 11 minutes.

Comment: @Wes isn't i >=0 instead of i>0?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to your assignment to the length of the array.

```
var i = matrixArray.length;
```

This makes `i = 5` in the first iteration. However, as there are 5 elements, your indices go from 0 to 4 (inclusive), not 5. As a consequence, the condition must also include the 0 index, that is, `i >= 0`, and not `i > 0`.

A way to fix this is to assign the initial value to `length - 1`.

```
for (var i = matrixArray.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    rightToLeftHorizontalValues.push(matrixArray[i][i]);
}
```

Another way is to use the `while` syntax, which I tend to prefer when traversing stuff backwards.

```
var i = matrixArray.length;
while (i--) {
    rightToLeftHorizontalValues.push(matrixArray[i][i]);
}
```

Some may not like it, as it is using an expression with a side effect as a condition. I don't like it that much myself, but it sure is compact.